# How to add a Gaussian noise signal with zero-mean in a given data set?

Tags: measurements, instrumentation, statistics, signal, noise

I have a real-time velocity measurement data set in a excel (.xlsx) file. I want to add the Gaussian noise signal with zero mean in this real-time data to create three set of pseudo measurements. Could you please tell me how to do this in the excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula to produce the white noise for one cell.

`= 0.5*NORM.S.INV(RAND())`

Where:

- `0.5` : can change to any non-zero number. It will control the range of the data.
- `NORM.S.INV(RAND())` : produces a random number from -inf to inf, with mean zero and standard deviation
  1

you can create a column for noise with this equation, and then just add the data.

If you want to be thorough you can

- copy and **paste as values**, so that the data does not change in every iteration.
- And also perform autocorrelation (on the noise column) to verify that the data indeed are GWN ([autocorrelation for non-zero shifts/timelags is zero](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780471679370.app2))